# How to get root installation directory of any application from swing code?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, auto-update

I am designing a patch installer for an application. The first page (after welcome page) of the installer asks for the root directory of the installed application and a Browse button is provided for the user to choose the root directory. However, to facilitate the process I **want the installer to intelligently find the root installer directory and set it as default in the text field rather than keeping it blank** (As I have seen in many of the installers). What is the best way to accomplish the same?

```
private JButton getBrowseButton(JPanel panel) {
    final JButton browseBtn = new JButton(rm.getMessage("button.browse"));
    browseBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            JFileChooser jfChooser = new JFileChooser(); 
            jfChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            jfChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            jfChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            guiUtil.removeFilesOfTypeFromJFileChooser(jfChooser);     
            jfChooser.showOpenDialog(panel);
       }
    });
    return browseBtn;
}
```

I thought of using environment variables but the application does not set any environment variables which I could just `System.getenv(String path)` and get directly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I am desingning a patch insaller for an application."* That comes built-in to [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: So what exactly your "patch installer" is? - where is it placed relative to the main application? isn't your installation directory the same as the application working directory?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you basically haven't provided enough information to give some specific answer to your question

Comment: Patch Installer would be like an executable desktop application. Just by starting it the installer would start. Also this patch installer will upgrade the current version of application which is alread installed on the client's machine. (like an upgrade for the installed version). And since it will be available for download online, its place could be anywhere depending on where the client downloads it. 
For Example,
If my app is in C:\\MyApp, and patch installer exe is in C:\\Downloads, during the installation, the patch installer exe should detect C:\\MyApp as the root installation directory.

Comment: @MikleGarin Great comments. :) To the OP - Crusaderpyro be sure to add `@` before the person name to ensure the person is *notified* of a new comment.

Comment: *"Patch Installer would be like an executable desktop application."* And like was mentioned at the page about JWS *"JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, .. **automatic update** (including lazy downloads and **programmatic control** of updates).."*.  This is exactly what JWS was ***built for***.  Most of the rest of its features were tacked on as extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside that it is probably a BAD IDEA to try to implement this yourself (see the Question comments) ....

There is no way that is going to work for all applications, because installation directories are a convention, not a requirement.  Rather, it is necessary to implement this on a per-application / per-platform basis.  Here are some ideas.

- Wire the installation directory path into the wrapper script used to launch the application, and pass it as a system property, command line parameter or environment variable.
- Store the installation directory path in an application configuration file.
- Infer the installation directory path from location of the wrapper script.
- Infer the installation directory path from the classpath.
- Store the installation directory path in the Windows registry, or similar.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to use the Windows registry as of now because there is no opdate in the class path and also the application configuration file will also be within the application and hence cannot locate. Lets see how the registry thing works.

Comment: *"... the application configuration file will also be within the application and hence cannot locate"*.  Assuming that the application can locate its own configuration file, that should not be an issue.  But hey, it is just one alternative.